# Python create a numpy array of set size

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a numpy array of a set size. I have a numpy array containing 4 numbers. My question right now is how to fill the array with zeros till an arbitrary size e.g. 7 in this example

```
pos = np.array([1,4,6,8])
new_pos = np.array([1,4,6,8,0,0,0])
```

Comment: One way is `np.r_[pos, [0, 0, 0]]` another `newpos=np.zeros(7, dtype=int); newpos[:4]=pos`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
np.zeros(5) # returns array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
new_pos = pos.append(np.zeros(5))
```

5 has been used arbitrarily. In your case it will be 3.